# Alternatives to OBS Studio?

Tags: windows-7, emulator, video-recording

I have just been using OBS Studio to record gameplay on an emulator called Mednafen.  Here is what I should establish from the get-go:

1) Mednafen cannot be maximized.

2) It can run in fullscreen, but everything becomes choppy when OBS is recording it.

3) I am using Windows 7, and do not want to shell money out to upgrade to Windows 10.

Are there any programs I can use, in order to record Mednafen either by itself or in fullscreen, smoothly, in Windows 7?

Comment: It doesn't really answer your question, but last I checked you can still upgrade from Win 7 to Win 10 for free